# Theorem related to Trace map of a field extension

Tags: galois-theory

Let $ E/F$ be a finite separable extension. Then the map $ T_x:E \rightarrow F$ given by $ T_x(y)=Tr (xy)$ is an $ F$-linear map.Show that the map $ \psi: E \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(E,F)$ given by $ \psi(x)=Tr_x$ is an isomorphism.

$\text{Attempt:}$

If $ \psi(x)=Tr_x=0$ then $ Tr_x(y)=Tr(xy)=0$ for all $ y \in E.$ Hence for any $ e \in E,$ $ Tr_x(x^{-1}e)=Tr(e)=0.$ Thus $ Tr$ is the zero functional. This is a contradiction. Hence $ \psi$ is an injective linear map.

I'am unable to prove surjectivity. My professor suggested to use the fact that $\text{dim} (E)= \text{dim} (\text{Hom}(E,F))$
I didn't understand why these dimensions are equal.

Comment: The dimensions are equal since $\dim(E)=\dim_F(E)$ by definition, and $Hom(E,F)=E^*$.

Comment: Because given a finite dimensional vector space $V$ (like $E$ in this case) over a field $k$ (like $F$ in this case), it is a theorem that $$\dim_k V=\dim_kV^*$$where $V^*$ is the dual vector space $\mbox{Hom}(V,k)$

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks✌